# How to initialize BehaviorSubject from type?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have a custom type `dictionaryItemLanguage`:

```
type dictionaryItemLanguage = Map<string, Map<string, IDictItem>>;
```

I need initialize `BehaviorSubject` like:

`export const Dictionary: BehaviorSubject<dictionaryItemLanguage> = new BehaviorSubject(new Map<string, Map<string, IDictItem>>());`

but replace on `dictionaryItemLanguage`:

`export const Dictionary: BehaviorSubject<dictionaryItemLanguage> = new BehaviorSubject(new dictionaryItemLanguage());`

Is it possible in TypeScript? I tried DRY.

Comment: You should create a class definition instead if you wanna initialize with new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, what i see here is that you trying to use `type` as class/constructor function in statement and this wouldn't work:

```
export const Dictionary: BehaviorSubject<dictionaryItemLanguage> = new BehaviorSubject(new dictionaryItemLanguage());
```

The first statement would work, cause you work with existing Map class

```
export const Dictionary: BehaviorSubject<dictionaryItemLanguage> = new BehaviorSubject(new Map<string, Map<string, IDictItem>>());
```

Don't forget that all typescript stuff will gone after compile step and types and interfaces do not compile to anything, check yourself

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20IDictItem%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20dictionaryItemLanguage%20%3D%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20IDictItem%3E%3E%3B

If you wanted to use new operator you have at least create class.

If you wanted to have BehaviorSubject with items of your dictionaryItemLanguage type only, and you wanted to avoid new Map>() statement every time, i can suggest:

```
interface IDictItem {
    value: string;
}

type dictionaryItemLanguage = Map<string, Map<string, IDictItem>>;

const createDictionary: () => dictionaryItemLanguage = () => {
    return new Map<string, Map<string, IDictItem>>();
};

const dictionary = new BehaviorSubject<dictionaryItemLanguage>(createDictionary());
dictionary.getValue();
```

Here you have a function which will always return a new Map of your previously defined type `dictionaryItemLanguage`, and the return value of `dictionary.getValue();` 
will be `Map<string, Map<string, IDictItem>>` aka `dictionaryItemLanguage`, cause `type` is only type alias.